# having trouble with making custom JOptionPane dialogs

Tags: java, eclipse, button, joptionpane

So, before you go and say that I should do more research, I have been trying to figure this out for about a week now and this is kind of my last resort. Moving on, I'm trying to make a dialog box with multiple buttons; a calculator. Although, I don't know almost any of the methods of *javax.swing*. I only know the *JOptionPane* method and a little bit of *JTextField*. Please, if possible, give me a hint or some clues as to what i need to do so that I can figure it out myself. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

`JOptionPane` don't have the functionalities you are looking for. If you want a lot of more buttons populating your Dialog you need some other component. Here is a skeleton of a calculator. You have to add the logic:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class Calculator extends JDialog {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private JTextField textField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Calculator dialog = new Calculator();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public Calculator() {
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bye");
            }
        });
        setBounds(100, 100, 348, 234);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPanel.setLayout(null);
        {
            textField = new JTextField();
            textField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            textField.setBounds(12, 13, 323, 19);
            contentPanel.add(textField);
            textField.setColumns(10);
        }

        JButton button_8 = new JButton("8");
        button_8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField.setText("8 pressed");
            }
        });
        button_8.setBounds(79, 46, 55, 25);
        contentPanel.add(button_8);

        JButton button_9 = new JButton("9");
        button_9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField.setText("9 pressed");
            }
        });
        button_9.setBounds(146, 46, 55, 25);
        contentPanel.add(button_9);

        JButton button_4 = new JButton("4");
        button_4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField.setText("4 pressed");
            }
        });
        button_4.setBounds(12, 83, 55, 25);
        contentPanel.add(button_4);

        JButton button_5 = new JButton("5");
        button_5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField.setText("5 pressed");
            }
        });
        button_5.setBounds(79, 83, 55, 25);
        contentPanel.add(button_5);

        JButton button_6 = new JButton("6");
        button_6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField.setText("6 pressed");
            }
        });
        button_6.setBounds(146, 83, 55, 25);
        contentPanel.add(button_6);

        JButton button_1 = new JButton("1");
        button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField.setText("1 pressed");
            }
        });
        button_1.setBounds(12, 120, 55, 25);
        contentPanel.add(button_1);

        JButton button_2 = new JButton("2");
        button_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField.setText("2 pressed");
            }
        });
        button_2.setBounds(79, 120, 55, 25);
        contentPanel.add(button_2);

        JButton button_3 = new JButton("3");
        button_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField.setText("3 pressed");
            }
        });
        button_3.setBounds(146, 120, 55, 25);
        contentPanel.add(button_3);

        JButton button_0 = new JButton("0");
        button_0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField.setText("0 pressed");
            }
        });
        button_0.setBounds(12, 157, 122, 25);
        contentPanel.add(button_0);

        JButton button_point = new JButton(".");
        button_point.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField.setText(". pressed");
            }
        });
        button_point.setBounds(146, 157, 55, 25);
        contentPanel.add(button_point);

        JButton button_divide = new JButton("/");
        button_divide.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField.setText("/ pressed");
            }
        });
        button_divide.setBounds(213, 46, 55, 25);
        contentPanel.add(button_divide);

        JButton button_multiply = new JButton("*");
        button_multiply.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField.setText("* pressed");
            }
        });
        button_multiply.setBounds(213, 83, 55, 25);
        contentPanel.add(button_multiply);

        JButton button_subtract = new JButton("-");
        button_subtract.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField.setText("- pressed");
            }
        });
        button_subtract.setBounds(213, 120, 55, 25);
        contentPanel.add(button_subtract);

        JButton button_sum = new JButton("+");
        button_sum.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField.setText("+ pressed");
            }
        });
        button_sum.setBounds(213, 157, 55, 25);
        contentPanel.add(button_sum);

        JButton button_back = new JButton("<");
        button_back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField.setText("Back pressed");
            }
        });
        button_back.setBounds(280, 46, 55, 25);
        contentPanel.add(button_back);

        JButton button_clear = new JButton("C");
        button_clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField.setText("Clear pressed");
            }
        });
        button_clear.setBounds(280, 83, 55, 25);
        contentPanel.add(button_clear);

        JButton button_equals = new JButton("=");
        button_equals.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField.setText("= pressed");
            }
        });
        button_equals.setBounds(280, 120, 55, 62);
        contentPanel.add(button_equals);

        JButton button_7 = new JButton("7");
        button_7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField.setText("7 pressed");
            }
        });
        button_7.setBounds(12, 46, 55, 25);
        contentPanel.add(button_7);
        {
            JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
            buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
            getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. A clue: this was made using WindowBuiler for Eclipse. You should try it as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help! Even though it doesnt work with JOptionPane, this was massive help to me and I'll explore more on the subject of WindowBuilder while I'm in one of my study halls. Thanks again, hava a great day/night.